# Android Horizontal RecylerView shows the same item from the last item on adapter when scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i need some help. 
so i need to get list of data from firebase and put it in a horizontal recylerview. below is the code, i already doublecheck it and the code return correct data.

```
private void loadtags() {
    mDatabase.child("tags")
            .orderByChild("total")
            .limitToLast(8).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Tags> tagsmodel = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Tags tags = userSnapshot.getValue(Tags.class);
                tagsmodel.add(userSnapshot.getValue(Tags.class));
            }
            mAdaptertags.addAll(tagsmodel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "database error : " + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

above code resulted this data :
tag10, tag2, tag5, tag6, pengumuman, programming, stikom, html

then i put the data in recyclerview. below is the code

```
mAdaptertags = new RecyclerViewAdapter_itemchiptags();
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManagertags = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
resekeltags.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagertags);
resekeltags.setAdapter(mAdaptertags);
loadtags();
```

the problem is, at first (before i scrolled the recylerview) the order of the data is like this :
tag10, tag2, tag5, tag6, pengumuman, programming, stikom, html

and after i scroll it, the first data, tag10 changed into html.

why did it changed?

update
this is my viewholder code

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Chip tagname;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tagname = (Chip) view.findViewById(R.id.item_chiptags);
        }


        public void setData(final Tags tag, int posisi) {
            try {
                color = MaterialPalettes.INSTANCE.getRandomColorByLevel(MaterialPalettes.INSTANCE.getLEVEL_700());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error warna : " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(posisi != tagsList.size()-1){
                tagname.setChipText(tag.getKey()+" "+posisi);
                tagname.changeBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), color));}
        }

    }
```

and this is my adapter code

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter_itemchiptags() {
        this.tagsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter_itemchiptags.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.itemtags, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter_itemchiptags.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(tagsList.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tagsList.size();
    }

    public void addAll(List<Tags> tags) {
        int initialSize = tagsList.size();
        tagsList.addAll(tags);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(initialSize, tags.size());
    }
```

Comment: This is an intended behavior of `RecyclerView` - when you scroll through it, `viewHolder`s that leave the viewport are re used.

Comment: can you share your adapter code?

Comment: @Udit is right. We should see your adapter class before.

Comment: hi, i already add my viewholder and adapter code

Answer (score 0):

try to change `initialSize` like below

```
 public void addAll(List<Tags> tags) {
    int initialSize = tagsList.size()+1; //change here
    tagsList.addAll(tags);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(initialSize, tags.size());
}
```

Comment: still not working, the first value keep switching with the last value

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the below lines:

```
 if(posisi != tagsList.size()-1){
                tagname.setChipText(tag.getKey()+" "+posisi);
                tagname.changeBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), color));}
        }
```

Here the condition passes only when the adapter reaches the last item.
If size = 10, size - 1  = 9:

(size - 1) != position or 9 != 9

Comment: uh sorry i forgot to delete that line,